# How to redirect a child URL to parent post URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect this URL: `https://www.example.com/Parent-post/child-post/` to `https://www.example.com/Parent-post/`

Is there any code to redirect child post to parent post?

Actually, the child post page created by WordPress for a single image. I want all my image page to auto-redirect to the main post.

Comment: So no child-post should be reachable?

Comment: yes. if anyone lands on that Child post page by search engines I want to redirect them to the parent post.